# Pandas: How to create a new column by random seletct other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Example df:

```
   A B C
0  X 9 0
1  5 7 5
2  5 6 Y
```

Expect output as below. The column D's value is random selected from column A/B/C

```
   A B C D
0  X 9 0 X(random from column A)
1  5 7 5 7(random from column B)
2  5 6 Y Y(random from column C)
```

Comment: Does one value have to come from each column? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have no idea , be honest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy advanced indexing with [`numpy.random.randint`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html):

```
df['D'] = df.to_numpy()[np.arange(df.shape[0]),
                        np.random.randint(0, df.shape[1], df.shape[0])]
```

Example:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  X  9  0  X   # A
1  5  7  5  7   # B
2  5  6  Y  5   # A
```

If you wan exactly one value from each column, use a random permutation with [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
df['D'] = df.to_numpy()[np.arange(df.shape[0]),
                        np.random.choice(np.arange(df.shape[1]),
                                         df.shape[0], replace=False)]
```

Example:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  X  9  0  9   # B
1  5  7  5  5   # A
2  5  6  Y  Y   # C
```